# Volley Android JSON GET Return Code is 200 but response is empty

Tags: android, api, android-volley

Here is my code:

```
final JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                        URLHelper.REQUEST_STATUS_CHECK_API, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

@Override                  
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

.....
.....

utils.print("Response", "" + response.toString());

if (response.optJSONArray("data") != null && response.optJSONArray("data").length() > 0) {
....
....
```

a) Able to contact the server and return code is 200
b) But the "response" string and the "data" array is empty.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Here is the Postman result:

[PostMan Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kW9PB.png)

Comment: check on postman wats the result..

Comment: Same in PostMan also

Comment: what are you getting in postman

Comment: I get the bearer token and related info (expiry date, domain etc)

Comment: can you show what you get in postman?

Comment: then parse the response and show it into your project...

Comment: Shivam, as mentioned, even though the response code is 200, I am not getting the response in Android.  IF statement fails because "data" is empty.

Comment: @MyVision send me the response..